# Guzzle PHP: Parse XML returned from WebService

Tags: php, guzzle

I’m using Guzzle to call the USPS Address Validation Service, and getting XML in the response. I then get the body from the XML using the following:

```
$body = $response->getBody();
```

Which produces the following:

```
<AddressValidateResponse>
    <Address ID="0">
        <Error>
            <Number>-2147219400</Number>
            <Source>clsAMS</Source>
            <Description>Invalid City.  </Description>
            <HelpFile/>
            <HelpContext/>
        </Error>
    </Address>
</AddressValidateResponse>
```

I need to parse that to get the Description.

$body is currently an Object. I tried casting it to an Array, but get the following, which is not what I’m after:

```
array (
  '' . "\0" . 'GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Stream' . "\0" . 'stream' => NULL,
  '' . "\0" . 'GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Stream' . "\0" . 'size' => NULL,
  '' . "\0" . 'GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Stream' . "\0" . 'seekable' => true,
  '' . "\0" . 'GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Stream' . "\0" . 'readable' => true,
  '' . "\0" . 'GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Stream' . "\0" . 'writable' => true,
  '' . "\0" . 'GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Stream' . "\0" . 'uri' => 'php://temp',
  '' . "\0" . 'GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Stream' . "\0" . 'customMetadata' => 
  array (
  ),
)
```

Does anyone know how I can parse that $body to get the Description Node?

Thanks for any guidance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probably easiest way to handle simple tasks with XML in PHP is through [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($body);
// Or if you're dealing with a Guzzle Response, you can even do
// $xml = $response->xml();

foreach($xml->Address as $address)
{
    echo $address->Error->Description;
}
```

Of course you should also do some error checking etc.

Also, besides the [examples in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php), there are tons of articles and [answers here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php) on how to handle XML data in PHP. Make sure to check them out if you run into problems.